# UIModalTransitionStyle flip horizontal Issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transition, uimodalpresentationstyle

I am trying to show a custom View Controller as alert view in swift. Everything works fine but the problem is that transition style flipHorizontal behaves different on different ios versions. You can see my case in the following images. First image was taken from the simulator on which ios 12.1 installed.The second image was taken from my physical phone and it has ios 10.3.3 Why on my physical phone flip horizontal transition is different from the simulator one. How to get the same animation of the simulator on my physical phone. My code script is like below :

```
 customAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "howtoPlay") as! HowtoPlayViewController
        customAlert?.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        customAlert?.definesPresentationContext = true
        customAlert?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        customAlert?.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
        customAlert?.howtoPlayDelagate = self
        self.present(customAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you setting `isDoubleSided` somewhere?

Comment: No, i dont set anywhere

Comment: Hmm, well what if you _do_ set it (to false), does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, i tried it but nothing changed

Comment: Matt your solution worked, thank you. I tried customAlert!.view.layer.isDoubleSided = false

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys answer of the @matt in the comment part helped me. Solution is like below :

customAlert!.view.layer.isDoubleSided = false